# water speed of a river

Tags: vectors, physics

Problem:

A boats speed is **1,70 m/s** in still water.
It must cross a river with a width of **260 m**.
The boats starting point is the **origin on the xy-axsis** (on the shore).
It has to dock **110 m** to the right(in the positive x-direction) opposite of the starting point on the other shore(i.e. the point parallel to the starting point on the other side + 110 m).
The boat must sail in a **45°** angle relative to the shore(x-axis) to arrive at that point.

What is the speed of the water current(water flows to the negative x-direction)?

[image: Picture of the problem]

What I have done:

It semms to be a pretty simple vector problem.
Just subtract the vector of the boat in moving water from the vector of the boat in still water(direct route) to get the vector of water flow.

I did this and got a nonzero y component of the water flow, which can't be true.
How can it even be zero if only the sin(0°+180°*n)= 0 and the y components of the vectors aren't equal?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $v_b$ be the speed of boat in still water, $v_r$ is the speed of river. The speed of boat in $x$ direction (in still water at 45 degree angle): $v_x=v_b/\sqrt{2}$, the speed of boat in $y$ direction is $v_y=v_b/\sqrt{2}$. The river speed has negative $x$ direction as you correctly concluded. Thus, we need to subtract it from $v_x$. We have: $(v_b/\sqrt{2}-v_r)\cdot t=110$, $v_b/\sqrt{2} \cdot t=260$ (where $t$ is the time to cross the river). This will give us the equation to find $v_r$: $$\frac{v_b/\sqrt{2}}{v_b/\sqrt{2}-v_r}=\frac{260}{110}$$ Can you complete from here?

Comment: Where did you get sqrt(2) from?

Comment: @ΟΥΤΙΣ: $\cos (\pi/4)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

Comment: Thank you I see it now, because $\cos (\pi/4)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$

Comment: I've got (- 1,9) for an answer. Thank you very much for your help.
I couldn't see beyond vectors addition, so I couldn't think of a different approach.

Comment: @ΟΥΤΙΣ: Check your math, I am getting about -0.7. You can use vector approach too just remember that the magnitude of vectors will depend on time.

Comment: Isn't the rest just basic algebra?
With vb being 1,7 and vr being the unknown?
I checked every step but I still get the same result.

Comment: @ΟΥΤΙΣ: yes, $150v_b/\sqrt{2}=260v_r$; $v_r=\frac{150v_b}{260\sqrt{2}}\approx 0.69$

Comment: Finally got it via cross-multiplication.  
Thank you very much. I really appreciate your help.
I learned much by struggling with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sailing on a still 'river', the boat would arrive to the opposide side at the point $260\,m$ across the river *and* $260\,m$ along the river, due to the angle of $45^\circ$.

What is the length of this route? What time would it take the boat to sail it?

You know the boat actually ends its travel $110\,m$ along the river. That means water shifted the boat by $260-110=150$ meters during the jorney (or $260+110=370$ meters, depending on the direction of the $45^\circ$ angle). Divide it by the travel time and you'll get the river speed.